# Paint peeling off in thick sheets

Tags: repainting

I'm having an issue with my living room paint peeling off in thick sheets down to the plaster. I was in the process of removing door trim and unfortunately lifted off some of the paint. I tried to scrape off whatever was loose but it ended up coming off like wall paper.  The paint comes off in big hard sheets consisting of multiple layers of paint.

Now one of the walls is pretty much stripped down to what looks like a primer painted onto plaster   but the primer is very powdery and leaves a white cast on your finger.

I was planning to repaint the living room anyway but wasn't sure how to go about priming and painting this area.

Answer (score 1):

Remove any remaining paint so the wall is all the same surface.

If you are not going to texture the wall then you will need to use Spackle or drywall mud to fill all holes and voids and  sand smooth.
If you are going to texture then no need to worry about small anomalies as the texture will hide them, but big ones will need to be filled.

Next you will need to apply a good  [drywall sealer/primer](https://www.518painters.com/best-primer-drywall/)  before you are ready to paint. If you are not texturing then use a sandable primer so you can sand the wall smooth before painting. Smooth walls take a lot of time and prep.

**FYI.** Next time you need to remove trim take a utility knife and firmly cut along the trim where it meets the wall so you break the bond between the paint and the trim.

Interesting read: [How to Seal Damaged Drywall](https://www.uglyducklinghouse.com/charlie-the-kitchen/)

Comment: I would add that before applying the sealer/primer, the wall should be cleaned very well to remove any dust from sanding.